# condition block my form validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular-ng-if

Hello I have been blocked for several days on this problem

I explain to you I have an input or I apply a message according to some condition however I have another condition that says if it is a multiline text used a textarea if it is an inline use an input

When I set my condition *ngIf = "! multiline" in my input I have a problem I have the error message:

***Can not read property 'errors' of undefinied***

I have applied something, I have encapsulate in a div my input including my condition and I thus, add myModel && myModel.error so that the object is initialized

nothing works

if anyone has a solution I'm interested

this is my code :

```
<div class="input-container" [ngClass]="{
      'empty-value': !model,
      'focus': focus,
      'blur': !focus,
      'input-container-material': theme !== 'block' && theme !== 'inline',
      'input-container-block': theme === 'block',
      'input-container-inline': theme === 'inline',
      'disabled': disabled}">
  <div class="input-container__label color--{{labelColor || 'default'}}" *ngIf="label" (click)="_focusInputField()">
    <div class="mi__wrapper mi__wrapper--inline">
      <span>{{label}}<span *ngIf="required"> *</span></span>
      <i class="mi mi-question" *ngIf="help" [maeTooltip]="help"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container__content bg--{{bg || 'default'}} color--{{color || 'default'}} border--{{borderColor || 'default'}}">
    <div *ngIf="!multiline">
      <input
        #inputField
        class="input-container__input"
        *ngIf="!multiline"
        (focus)="onFocus()"
        (blur)="onBlur()"
        placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
        name="{{name}}"
        type="{{type || 'text'}}"
        pattern="{{pattern}}"
        minlength="{{minlength}}"
        maxlength="{{maxlength}}"
        min="{{min}}"
        max="{{max}}"
        [required]="required"
        autocomplete="{{autocomplete}}"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        [readonly]="readonly"
        [(ngModel)]="model"
        #myModel="ngModel"
      />
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputContent"></ng-container>

    <div *ngIf="multiline" class="input-container__multiline">
      <div class="input-container__input input-container__multiline__place-holder">{{model}}</div>
      <textarea
        #inputFieldMultiline
        class="input-container__input input-container__multiline__input"
        [(ngModel)]="model"
        (focus)="onFocus()"
        (blur)="onBlur()"
        placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
        name="{{name}}"
        minlength="{{minlength}}"
        maxlength="{{maxlength}}"
        [required]="required"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        [readonly]="readonly"
        #myModel="ngModel"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputContent"></ng-container>
  {{hint}}
</div>

<ng-template #inputContent>
  <div class="input-container__hints" *ngIf="this.theme !== 'inline'">
    <div class="input-container__hints--left">
      <div *ngIf="myModel && myModel.errors && myModel.touched" class="alert-error">
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.required">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.required}}
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.minlength">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.minlength}}
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.maxlength">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.maxlength}}
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!myModel.errors.pattern">
          <i class="mi mi-warning"></i>
          {{ValidationHints.pattern}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container__hints--right" *ngIf="withCharCount">
      {{(model?.length || 0) + (maxlength ? ('/' + maxlength) : '')}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

thanks

Comment: Could we see the TypeScript code in the component? I'm assuming myModel is not initialized when the component first loads.

Comment: my typescript code is on the answer

Comment: any answer ????

Comment: If you'd strip your code to the bare minimum to showcase the issue, improves your chances to get answers. I bet 95% of that code is not necessary (?) and for example I am not trying to find your error in that much code. Strip down the code and point exactly where the error is thrown :)

Comment: The whole HTML5 code is necessary as regards the typescript not much is useful to my problem however I ask it then I put it

Comment: Well the same error would probably be shown with one or two form controls and like one validation per control instead of all of lots of those. We encourage the minimal code to reproduce the issue. Buuut it was just a suggestion :) Best would be to create a plunker :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  forwardRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core'
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
} from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'mae-input',
  templateUrl: './input.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  host: {
    class: 'input-form'
  }
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() theme: string = 'material' // 'material' or 'block' or 'inline'
  @Input() minlength: number
  @Input() maxlength: number
  @Input() min: number
  @Input() max: number
  @Input() pattern: string
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-reserved-keywords
  @Input() type: string
  @Input() autocomplete: string
  @Input() required
  @Input() disabled
  @Input() readonly
  @Input() multiline: boolean
  @Input() withCharCount: boolean
  @Input() label: string
  @Input() name: string
  @Input() placeholder: string
  @Input() help: string
  @Input() hint: string
  @Input() bg: string
  @Input() color: string
  @Input() borderColor: string
  @Input() labelColor: string
  @Input() myModel: any

  ValidationHints = {

    required: ' Please fill out this field.',
    minlength: ' Field must be at least 3 characters long.',
    maxlength: ' Field cannot be more than 24 characters long.',
    pattern: ' Please match the requested format.'
  }
  focus: boolean = false

  @ViewChild('inputField')

  private _inputField: ElementRef

  @ViewChild('inputFieldMultiline')

  private _inputFieldMultiline: ElementRef

  private _model: string

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
  onChange: any = () => {
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
  onTouched: any = () => {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.required = this.required !== undefined && this.required !== false
    this.disabled = this.disabled !== undefined && this.disabled !== false
    this.readonly = this.readonly !== undefined && this.readonly !== false
    this.myModel = ''
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model
  }

  set model(val: string) {
    if (val === this._model) {
      return
    }
    this._model = val
    this.onChange(val)
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._model = value
    this.cd.markForCheck()
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }

  onFocus() {
    if (this.readonly || this.disabled) {
      return
    }
    this.focus = true
  }

  onBlur() {
    if (this.readonly || this.disabled) {
      return
    }
    this.focus = false
    this.onTouched()
  }

  _focusInputField() {
    if(!this.readonly && !this.disabled) {
      if (this.multiline) {
        this._inputFieldMultiline.nativeElement.focus()
      } else {
        this._inputField.nativeElement.focus()
      }
    }
  }
}
```